# What do call someone who is too slow?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

For instance you're driving and there's a car ahead of you, it is very slow and hesitant. You find it irritating, what do you call the driver?
Is there an expression to describe him or her?

Comment: A *sloth*, a *sluggard*, a %##$&!

Comment: A [slowpoke](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slowpoke) for instance

Comment: Native English speakers generally do not say 'How do you call...?' in the way your question does. We say 'What do you call...?' Re @MorganFR 's suggestion, 'slowpoke' is American English Usage, the british English equivalent would be 'slowcoach'.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer and correction. 
I was wondering if there was a remark that would naturally show your annoyance when being in that driving situation.   But it could also apply when someone makes you wait too long for something. In French (my native language) we literally say 'smart as a broomstick's handle'. It's a criticism, you think the person is too slow in his or her reaction.

Answer (score 2):

A common term is **[Sunday Driver](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sunday-driver)**. From the Random House dictionary:

> noun
>   1.
>   a person who drives a car inexpertly, especially slowly or overcautiously, in the manner of one who drives infrequently.

Comment: Thank you very much, it makes sense, we have this expression in French too. Yet I was wondering it there could be a darker remark, like a criticism showing your annoyance.